# Remove fields from registration form

Tags: magento-1, customer, validation, form-validation, registration

I'm trying to modify my registration form on Magento removing the firstname, lastname and the password confirmation.

At the moment I've changed the "**is_required**" in the "**eav_attribute**" table for **FirstName** and **LastName** (not sure if there is something also for the password confirmation).

I've updated the code here

> **public_html/ec/app/design/frontend/typologancee/default/template/customer/form
>   register.phtml**

in order to remove the 3 fields from the UI

I've removed the code

```
['validate-cpassword', 'Please make sure your passwords match.', function(v) {
    var conf = $('confirmation') ? $('confirmation') : $$('.validate-cpassword')[0];
    var pass = false;
    if ($('password')) {
        pass = $('password');
    }
    var passwordElements = $$('.validate-password');
    for (var i = 0; i < passwordElements.size(); i++) {
        var passwordElement = passwordElements[i];
        if (passwordElement.up('form').id == conf.up('form').id) {
            pass = passwordElement;
        }
    }
    if ($$('.validate-admin-password').size()) {
        pass = $$('.validate-admin-password')[0];
    }
    return (pass.value == conf.value);
}],
```

from

> **/public_html/ec/js/prototype/validation.js**

I removed

> if (!Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getFirstname()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
>               $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The first name cannot be empty.');
>           }
>
> ```
>     if (!Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getLastname()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
>         $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The last name cannot be empty.');
>     }
> ```

in

> **/public_html/ec/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php**

Now I'm still getting an error during the registration:

> Please make sure your passwords match.

Also changing

> $confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
>           if ($password != $confirmation) {
>               $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
>           }

with

> $confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
>           if ($password != $confirmation) {
>               $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
>           }

nothing happen.
Do you have idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem resolved :)
I had just to remove the last part about the confirmation and not update it.

Comment: Yes this does answer the question and is not a thank you comment.....